# Равенство строк динамического двумерного массива

Tags: c

Стоит задача в сравнении отсортированных двумерных динамических массивов, они равны, если для каждой строки одного массива есть только одна такая же строка в другом массиве:

```
void array_check(int** array1,int** array2, int width1, int width2)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<width1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<width2;j++)
        {
         if(array1[i]==array2[j])
             count++;
        }
        if(count!=1)
        {
          printf("Not equal");
          break;
        }
        count=0;
        if(i=width1)
        {
            printf("Equal");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять как правильно сравнить строки т.к при такой функции строки всегда не равны.

Comment: Да, при такой функции строки всегда не равны, так как у вас условие в if i = width1 (думаю, вы имели в виду ==, а не =), но цикл по i запущен до i < width1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение сводится к простому по-элементному сравнению массивов. Докажу это.

Допустим, что первая строка из массива `array1` находится не на первой позиции в массиве `array2`. Это возможно, если либо один из, или оба массива не отсортированы, что противоречит требованиям. Либо, если в массиве `array2` на предыдущих позициях находятся другие строки не равные данной, это возможно если эти предущие строки из массива `array2` отсутсвуют в `array1`, либо что они повторяются несколько раз. Это противоречит условию равенства и следовательно массивы не равны.

Повторяя описанную проверку для каждой строки можно сделать заключение о равенстве массивов.

По технической части вопроса. Вы не правильно сравниваете строки, вот это `array1[i] == array2[j]` сравнит лишь указатели на строки. Чтобы по-символьно их сравнить можно использовать стандартную функцию `strcmp`, вот так `0 == strcmp(array1[i], array2[j])`.